# Foursquare - Menus are not displaying in API Explorer for certain venues

Tags: php, html, css, foursquare

When I run the following url in browser window:

https://foursquare.com/v/mr-teriyaki-burlingame-ca/4b269e61f964a5206f7e24e3/menu

Result:

Here the menu results are displaying,

[image]

When I run the following url in browser window using the endpoints 'venues/Venue_id/menu':

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4b269e61f964a5206f7e24e3/menu?oauth_token=LGY1ITAR5MBHYZXKRRKVDFXKJAUT43ATZT1GBCFKB2NLMSYY&v=20140627

Result:

Here the menu results are not getting but the venue id is correct,

[image]

So kindly give me the solution to why the menu details are not get displayed in foursquare api explorer window using the endpoinds 'venues/Venue_id/menu'.

Thanks,

Arularasan D,

PHP Programmmer.

Comment: how you solve your problem am getting same problem any help ...

Comment: We didnt get any solution to resolve this issue.. Can anyone give the idea to resolve this?